# Вытянуть слово из url

Tags: php

Есть ссылки вида:

`https://m.avito.ru/moskva/rasteniya/orhideya_falen...`
`https://m.avito.ru/kazan/rasteniya/orhideya_falen...`
и т.д.

Каждая ссылка находится допустим в переменной $url

Как из этой ссылки выделить города **moskva**, **kazan** и т.д.?

То есть нужно чтобы в итоге при `echo $gorod` выводился город.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo current(explode("/",end(explode(".ru/",$url,2)),2));
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!